# Usage of XSD xs:anyType

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to have XML parsers for a couple of about 20 schemata, representing different sets of domain data.
The instances share a common part INFO, but have an individual part DATA, which is different between the schemata. So the xml instances have all the same element type INFO, but different element types for DATA.

Now, when I receive a piece of XML, I want first to know, to which type of schema it belongs. This information is part of INFO. Then I parse against the right schema, to extract data. To find out the type, I want to implement a "common" parser, where DATA is of type=**xs:anyType** and its content is ignored during parsing, since I get data at the second step.

Since I dont't want to put all different domain types into one single schema, there is the disadvantage of not knowing in advance the right schema to apply. I could apply all different parsers and check for validation errors, but that is not very efficient.

Is this solution acceptable, or is the a better solution?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I cannot imagine yet, how substitutionGroups or xsi:type can help me to avoid multistage parsing. Does it mean, one single parser has to know about all different types of DATA? That would mean, I have to put all variants for DATA into one XSD. Right?

Comment: Please ask another question. For an example of this, check how GML and GML profiles work. You don't have to put everything in one XSD file but the parser must know your schemas, yes.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say without diving in your specific case.

I generally dislike `xs:anyType` and kinds since they're just too generic. Schemas loose their structuring purpose with these types/elements.

I think in your case you just want some flexible polymorphic/inhertitance construct.

You may consider the following options:

- Use `xsi:type` on `DATA` to specify, which specific type it exactly is. This may help you avoid two-phase parsing in certain environments (in Java, JAXB, for instancs, handles `xsi:type` gracefully).
- Consider using `substitutionGroups`. You may define `DATA` as an abstract element which may then be substituted via different concrete elements (individual `DATA`).

Remember, XML Schema is very often a way to define the exchange protocoll.  So using a totally generic construct like `any` basically says "just send me something". It will be impossible to understand what's expected without knowing your implementation.

For the internal use cases anything is fine, but internal things often go public, sometimes on a very short notice.